# Javascript -- wait for user interaction without freezing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't speak English very well.

My company has developed a web application for internet explorer that very strenuously uses the function `showModalDialog` and waits for the result.

We are planning to extend the use of the application to other browsers (Firefox, Chrome), and I need to replace "`showModalDialog` logic" with a logic that will work well on all browsers.

I originally tried using an `ajaxcontroltoolkit` `modalpopup` with an `iframe` inside.

My problem is that, after I have showed the `modalpopup`, I cannot wait for the user to close the popup window without freezing the web interface.

```
function OpenDialog() {
    var result = window.showModalDialog("page1.html", "input_parameter", "width:100px; height:100px");

    //When the popup went closed
    alert("result: " + result);
}

//Override showModalDialog function for compatibility with other browser
function myShowModalDialog(url, pars, options) {

    //show a jquery modalpopup or ajaxcontroltoolkit modalpopup with an iframe ....
    iframe.src = url;

    //I need to wait here until the modal popup closed
    //HOW?

    //get the value from popup
    var res = ???????;

    return res;
}

window.showModalDialog = myShowModalDialog;
```

I cannot change the logic for every page in the webapp.

I searched for a method to override the `showModalDialog` function and recreate the same logic (wait until the popup is closed and get the result that the popup provides for the caller).

Any ideas? Thanks to all

Comment: Consider to design an absolutely positioned panel instead of open a window or waiting for iframe aso. You could create a full size overlay that catches all events and cancels them.

Comment: You can't create a modal dialog in the sense that your code waits. Instead, use events and trigger an event when your dialog is closed. Retrieve your result from that instead of waiting for it in your code.

Comment: @Quasimodo: Yes, i would to use this component: http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Comment: @abmitchell: unfortunately i cannot modify the code for all page in my application!

Comment: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/. You have no other choice than to make your code asynchronous. Sorry.

Comment: @bdn02 I understand that's the way the app was written, but there is no way to make it wait for a result without locking up. You simply have to use events, and that's going to mean re-writing a bunch of logic if you want to deploy this across different browsers

Comment: I think that you are right. I now search the best method to modify the pages. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You've discovered the reason why JavaScript relies heavily on asynchronicity, event handlers, and callback functions.

The best solution would be to restructure your code so that your events trigger on event handlers, using jQuery or somesuch to bind the event handlers to the event. Alternatively, you could always use a function in a [timeout loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to check periodically if the modal is closed yet, and execute the continuation of your code when it is. That's pretty hacky though, and I don't recommend it. In general, trying to force asynchronous code to fit a synchronous model gets really messy.

Comment: I agree with event handlers, but disagree with timeout loops. If he added a timeout loop in `OpenDialog()`, that would still lock up the browser

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not following you, what you need is a callback when the user closes the dialog, right?

Whatever method is executed when the user closes the dialog, monkey patch it to call your function.  (A monkey patch is code that adds functionality to existing code, but keeps the old code also).

So if your close method/function looks like:

```
myCloseDialog = function(){
  // do important closing stuff
}
```

Then you can monkey patch like so:

```
myNewCloseDialog = function(){
  // do important callback stuff, or call your callback function
  myCloseDialog(arguments);
}
```

By the way, your English is very fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a short demo of my suggestion in the comment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>modal overlay</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      .overlay
      {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index: 100;
        margin:0;
        display:none;
      }
      .box
      {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        width:400px;
        height:300px;
        background:white;
        margin:auto;
        padding:10px;
      }

    </style>

    <!--
      prepare a style to show/hide overlay and
      prevent lost focus when clicking outside the box
    -->
    <template id="template1">
      <style id="style-modal">
        *
        { pointer-events: none;
        }
        .overlay *
        {pointer-events: auto;
        }
        .overlay
        { display:block!important;
        }
      </style>
    </template>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="some-input1" type="text">
    <button class="modal-open" type="button">open modal dialog</button>

    <div id="overlay1" class="overlay">
      <div class="box">
        <input id="modal-input1" type="text">
        <button type="button" class="modal-close">close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener
      ( 'DOMContentLoaded',
        function(ev)
        {
          var
            template1  = document.getElementById('template1'),
            styleModal = template1.content.getElementById('style-modal'),
            overlay1   = document.getElementById('overlay1'),
            box        = overlay1.querySelector('.box'),
            head       = document.querySelector('head')
          ;

          //TODO: could iterate over querySelectorAll
          document.querySelector('button.modal-open').addEventListener
          ( 'click',
            function(ev) { head.appendChild(styleModal); },
            false
          )

          overlay1.querySelector('button.modal-close').addEventListener
          ( 'click',
            function(ev)
            { template1.content.appendChild(styleModal);
              document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('closemodal', {detail:{relatedTarget:box}}));
            },
            false
          )
        },
        false
      );

      document.addEventListener
      ( 'closemodal',
        function(ev){ alert(ev.detail.relatedTarget.querySelector('input').value); },
        false
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that this example makes use of `<template>` element which isn't implemented by IE yet. You can easily generate the style-element in the script, hold it in a variable and add/remove it to/from the head.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, but my problem is not the overlay. My problem is that i have a function (dialog opener function, button.modal-open click in you example) that can wait until the modal have been closed

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my [showModalDialog polyfill](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog) using a modal  element and ECMAScript 6 generators, so it does not need an explicit callback function. Statements after `showModalDialog()` will run after closing the modal.